# How does an Android app on Google TV display in the overscan area (youtube can why can't I?)

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen

This is for Google TV...

I have been through the layout xml multiscreen stuff and this is what I've come up with:

in my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginRight="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    >

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="1920dp"
        android:layout_height="1080dp"

        >
    </SurfaceView>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="1920dp"
        android:layout_height="1080dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text=" "
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

put this into my manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

added the "special sauce" to my java main.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And I can display out to the edge of my "allowed" display area just fine.  but I'm limited to about 10% less on the edges of my screen space than youtube.  The docs say "I'm not allowed" do use that area but clearly youtube and Netflix do.  How do they do this?

Comment: FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN

maybe that's what you're looking for?